# C++ Default values in functions?

Tags: c++, default-value

How exactly do default values in functions work? My question pertains to this example:

```
int func(int number, std::string name = "None", int anotherNumber);

..

int func(int number, std::string name, int anotherNumber){
    ...
}

func(1, 2);
^Error, name is NULL yet we've defined a default value?
```

The compiler gives an error complaining that the argument was NULL and should not be. Yet I've defined a default value for it.

Why is this?

Comment: That should not be the only error. You can't give just any argument a default value, they have to be at the end of the argument list.

Comment: Why must it be at the end? Is it just something C++ does that we can't really do anything about?

Comment: You're not showing the real error. Don't make things up; paste them from your output.

Comment: @JoeBid: Consider `void f(int, int = 1, int = 2, int);`. What does `f(3, 4, 5)` mean?

Comment: Mm I suppose I understand now. Makes sense.

Comment: Your declaration of `func` is illegal, your compiler should reject it

Comment: What's wrong with it Matt?

Answer (score 5):

If a default parameter at position `k` is supplied, all parameters in positions from `k+1` to the end must be supplied as well. C++ allows you to omit parameters only in the end positions, because otherwise it has no way of matching parameter expressions to formal parameters.

Consider this example:

```
int func(int a, int b=2, int c, int d=4);
...
foo(10, 20, 30);
```

This call is ambiguous, because it supplies three parameters out of four. If declaration above were allowed, C++ would have a choice of calling

```
func(10, 20, 30, 4);
```

or

```
func(10, 2, 30, 40);
```

With all defaulted parameters at the end and a rule that parameters are matched by position, there would be no such ambiguity:

```
int func(int a, int b, int c=2, int d=4);
...
foo(10, 20, 30); // means foo(10, 20, 30, 4);
```

Comment: By "parameter expressions" do you mean "arguments"?

Comment: By "default parameter" do you mean "default argument"?

Comment: @KerrekSB Although C++ standard sometimes refers to "actual parameters" as "arguments", this hasn't quite caught up in the wider programming community, where "parameter" and "argument" are often used interchangeably. I briefly considered writing "actual parameters" in place of "parameter expressions", but decided that that would be too formal.

Comment: "because otherwise it has no way of matching parameter expressions to formal parameters." It could also be the other way around, with the defaulted parameters first. It is a choice between two workable options.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's true. Moreover, one could come up with other ways to address this - e.g. by allowing users to specify parameters in arbitrary order, and require specifying formal parameter names in the invocation Ada-style.

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments are last.

```
int func(int number1, int number2, std::string = "none");
...
func(1,2);
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument